# Atribuir valor dinâmico para uma variável em Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Procurei muito e não encontrei a resposta.

Preciso atribuir um valor a uma variável em Jquery, não possuo muito conhecimento. O que preciso é:

Ao clicar em um link:

```html
<a href="?sts=Pendente" title="Avisos Pendentes" id="Pendente" data-statusTipo="Pendente">
```

Uma variável chamada  sts1  tenha o valor do  id  acima:

```
var sts1 = $('a').on(click (function() {
  $('a:hover', this).data('statusTipo');
}));
```

Só isso... já tentei de tudo e não consegui...

Agradeço a atenção

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando usas `$('a').on(click (function() {` o jQuery chama essa função quando o elemento receber o evento. Dentro dessa função o `this` recebe um indicador para o elemento. Assim, dentro dessa função podes usar:

```
var id = this.id; // para saber o id
var status = this.dataset.statusTipo; // para aceder a `data-`
```

Assim podes usar:

```
$('a').on(click (function() {
    var id = this.id; // para saber o id
    var status = this.dataset.statusTipo; // para aceder a `data-`
    alert(id + ' ' + status);
}));
```

Comment: funcionou obrigado pelo retorno

Comment: só fiquei com uma dúvida, pra eu usar essa variável em outra função tenho que usar sem o "var"... é isso?

Comment: @TiagoBuzatto exato. Se usares o `var` vais re-iniciar a variável e ela perde o valor antigo.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var sts1 = '';

 $('a').click(function() {
   sts1 = $(this).data('statusTipo');
 });
});
```

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno, funcinou sim, abs

Comment: Por favor marque a melhor resposta como solução

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, Jquery possui uma função chamada `attr()`.
A sintaxe do comando é:

```
$( seletor ).attr( 'nome_atributo' );
```

Agora para resolver seu problema, faça:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var sts1 = '';

     $( 'a' ).click(function() {
         sts1 = $(this).attr( 'data-statusTipo' );
     });

});
```

Espero que te ajude.

Comment: funcionou também, resolveu... abs e obrigado

Comment: Escolha a solução de +1 e sete como melhor resposta